# Limitations of get-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityRecommendation PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

We are trying to list available recommendations, however, the list is limited to top 4 records of total 10 records. We are using this command: Get-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityRecommendation -ResourceGroupName resourceGroup -ServerName server -DatabaseName database. Is there a way around to get this command to list all available recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, the command `Get-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityRecommendation` can be used to list available recommendations. But it can only display up to 4 records in windows. The other records will only show as `...`.
[image]

So if you want to show all records, please refer to the following script

```
$result=Get-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityRecommendation -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroup> -ServerName <server> -DatabaseName <database>
$result.SensitivityLabels
```

[image]
[image]